# Como fazer colunas responsivas com GridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

No caso preciso que quando estiver em portrait apresente um número de colunas que completem a largura da tela e quando em landscape o os itens no recyclerview sejam apresentados em um número de colunas proporcionais a nova largura, evitando que fique disforme as proporções dos cardviews.

Comment: Adicione a pergunta o layout dos itens da RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Use o `getRotation()`:

```
WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

if (manager != null) {
    Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();

    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
        //em LADNSCAPE atribuimos uma quantidade de colunas maior a sua recycler view
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
    } else {
        //em PORTRAIT uma quantidade menor
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    }
}
```

Você pode executar este código em seu `onCreate`, quando estiver configurando sua UI.

Link para a documentação da classe: [Display](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation())

Comment: E no caso de eu implementar meu recyclerview em um fragment, utilizaria desse código, ou teria outra maneira para esse caso?

Comment: A única diferença é que você precisaria alocar esse código no `onCreateView` de seu Fragment. Funciona normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! E desculpe pela demora em agradecer. Funcionou direito aqui.